# Java Regex: repetitive groups?

Tags: java, regex

How can I define repetitive groups in Java Regex?

Lets say a 2digit number [0-9]{2} multiple times separates by ,

```
12,34,98,11
```

Is that possible or a split by , the only chance?

Edit: I like to validate AND extract.

Comment: Use `\b\d{2}(?=,|$)` regex and use in `while (matcher.find()` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a two-step solution: 1) first, validate the string, then 2) split the string with the delimiter of your choice:

```
String[] chunks = null;
if (s.matches("\\d{2}(?:,\\d{2})*")) {
    chunks = s.split(Pattern.quote(","));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chunks)); // => [12, 34, 98, 11]
}
```

Here, `s.matches("\\d{2}(?:,\\d{2})*")` matches the whole string that starts with two digits and then contains 0 or more occurrences of `,` and two digits to the end, and then `s.split(Pattern.quote(","))` splits the string with a comma. Note you do not need `^` and `$` anchors with a pattern inside `matches()` since the method requires a full string match.

**If you have to do that with a single regex**, you may use multiple matches anchored to the start of string and end of each successful preceding match, only if the string check at the start of the string is a success:

```
(?:\G(?!^),|^(?=\d{2}(?:,\d{2})*$))(\d{2})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TubQCs/1/).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^),|^(?=\d{2}(?:,\d{2})*$))` - end of the preceding successful match and then a `,` (see `\G(?!^),`) or (`|`) start of string (`^`) that is followed with two digits and then 0 or more sequences of a `,` and two digits to the end of the string (see `\d{2}(?:,\d{2})*$`)
- `(\d{2})` - Group 1: two digits

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/pBG6ch):

```
String s = "12,34,98,11";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\G(?!^),|^(?=\\d{2}(?:,\\d{2})*$))(\\d{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    results.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(results); 
// => [12, 34, 98, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java you may also use `Scanner` APIs for this:

```
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}");
Scanner scan = new Scanner("12,34,98,11");
scan.useDelimiter(",");
while(scan.hasNext(pat)) {
    System.out.println( "Token: " + scan.next() );
}
scan.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's supported in Java Regex. See [Pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Here's an example:

```
"11,12,13".matches("\\d{2}(,\\d{2})*"); // true
```

You can then split the string with [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or a [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Examples:

```
String[] split = "11,12,13".split(",");
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer("11,12,13", ",");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("11,12,13").useDelimiter(",");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // scanner.next()
}
```